# Sorting items of array based on same item and creating multidimensional arrays

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sorting

So I am working out of a previous question I asked  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14363888/creating-wrapper-div-using-loops-and-ng-class-in-angularjs), in which I talked about making a history timeline from a JSON file using AngularJS. Essentially, the JSON file contains a bunch of HISTORY EVENTS object, each of them containing an ID called "theDate" to indicate the date at which these unique events took place. I want to sort all of the events into their specific DECADES for navigation purposes later in the view and using CSS.

I'm struggling with creating a multidimensional array whose structure should be something like this (this should be the MASTER array):

```
[[all of 1960s events],[all of 1970s events], [all of 1980s events]...]
```

...In which each of those specific arrays within the MASTER array contains event objects for that specific decade. (For example, for the 1960s array, the events should contain the years `[ 1961, 1963, 1969,etc.]`.

Working with AngularJS, I have my working code here:

```
        var events = $scope.events;

    function decadeSort(){

        var year;
        var arrayOfYears = [];


        for(var i = 0; i<events.length; i++){

            var date = new Date(events[i].theDate);
            year = date.getFullYear();

            var yearToString = year.toString();
            var yearToDecade = yearToString.substring(0,3).concat("0");
            arrayOfYears.push(yearToDecade);


        }
        console.log(arrayOfYears);
    };

    decadeSort();
```

The `arrayOfYears` array prints out all the YEAR of the 267 event objects according to their respective DECADE like this:

```
["1960","1960","1970","1970","1970","1980","1980","1990","1990","2000","2000"..]
```

With some of the string objects in THAT array repeat, I was hoping to create new arrays WITHIN that array based on which objects are the same strings. I don't know how to write this loop, so any insight and help would be greatly appreciate.

Thank you so much!

Comment: could you add an excerpt of `events` (maybe using `JSON.stringify` for easier copying). Also if the previous answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted. You're already at only 50%, and people will stop helping you sooner or later.

Comment: thanks @Yoshi for your help, I accepted the other helps. So, here is one `events`; this one is `events[0]`, I have 267 `events` altogether: `{"theDate":"1968-10-11","label":"Black students burn yearbook, citing omission of blacks and white middle-class slant.","category":"race; student-of-color; African-American","typeOfProtest":"burning","president":"Edwin Etherington (1967-1970)","id":0}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the sample-event you posted, the following is a simply way to group-by decade:

```
var grouped = {};

events.forEach(function (event) {
  var decade = Math.floor((new Date(event.theDate)).getFullYear() / 10) * 10;
  if (typeof grouped[decade] === 'undefined') {
    grouped[decade] = [];
  }

  grouped[decade].push(event);
});

console.log(grouped);
```

It's using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) which you might need to change, if you're targeting a browser that does not support it.